# how to print child window in nwjs

Tags: java, node.js, html, nwjs

In NWJS, I would like to print the second window which showing up. i tried doing this :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script>
    nw.App.registerGlobalHotKey(new nw.Shortcut({
      key: "F11",
      active: function() {
        nw.Window.get().toggleFullscreen();
      }
    }));

    nw.App.registerGlobalHotKey(new nw.Shortcut({
      key: "ctrl+p",
      active: function() {
        window.print();
        headerFooterEnabled: false;
      }
    }));
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="quick" src="https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_open_link_in_new_window.cfm" style="display:inline-flex; position:fixed; width: 100%; height:100%; bottom:0; right:0; top:0; left:0;"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

The script run normallly, until i click link inside nwjs's frame, which open a new window (The second window).
i want to print those second window, but the print preview always showing the first window.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

How deeply nested your frame may be is irrelevant as long as it has an ID to make it accessible.

So this always works for me...

> FrameID.focus(); FrameID.contentWindow.print();